# Does hibernate have something like the eclipselink copygroups

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

In eclipselink, one can use a feature called copygroup, which is basically a concept similar to the entitygraph of jpa 2.1 by which one can obtain, copies of entities specifying which attributes and relationships of the entity graph can be copied.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/AttributeGroup#Copy_Examples

is there a feature in hibernate that allows partial copying of entity object graphs using a copygroup / entity graph?

Answer (score 0):

JPA 2.2 doesn't exist. JPA 2.1 provides Entity graphs, and that is available in ANY JPA 2.1 implementation (DataNucleus 3.3+, EclipseLink 2.5+, Hibernate 4.3+). That is the whole point of having something in a spec

Comment: Just reworded the question, I was asking if hibernate can copy objects using an entity graph?